# Docker: Level of separation between database, client and API

Tags: docker

I always separate client, database and API into completely separate scopes (i.e. they are designed to run on separate servers). Should this separation also be reflected when you set up your Docker compose? I feel relatively confident in separating the client (for example Vue or React project) into its own scope with its own docker compose file.

But I have some doubt as to how I should handle the API and the database. Are they expected to be two completely separate scopes with their own Docker and docker-compose files? Or are they expected to be in the same docker-compose?

I understand that both are possible - I'm interested in what's considered the best practice :-)

I hope the question is phrased to make sense. Thanks in advance

Comment: Running these parts separately makes sense to me, particularly if you have a strong network API between the client and server layers.  You could consider running the database on its own host not in a container, since its lifecycle is so different from the application's.  In development I might run the server and its database together.  But..."it depends", and there are tradeoffs between complexity and robustness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, when talking about the same overall application you'd use one `docker-compose.yml` file and a different `Dockerfile` for each one if building them yourself.

If you check out [this](https://github.com/getsentry/onpremise/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) commercial application docker-compose file you can see their entire stack is defined in a single compose file.

If you're interested in best practices maybe check out Kubernetes or its simple one machine (node) personal use product [minikube](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/). generally, if you run these services not in production a compose file would be just fine, but, if you care about redundancy with resources and minimizing downtime (i.e. you have 3 machines, one becomes unavailable but the other two still have the other app instances running on them) then Kubernetes might be a better option